# Command Binding, KeyBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

У меня имеется проблемка с привязкой кнопок на элементе.
У меня имеется хамл:

```
<MediaElement.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=KeyPressedCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                        Key="Enter" />
</MediaElement.InputBindings>
```

И ViewModel:

```
public RelayCommand KeyPressedCommand { get; set; }
...
KeyPressedCommand = new RelayCommand(x => KeyPressed(x));
...
private void KeyPressed(object mediaElement)
    {
        Watch.Stop();
        (mediaElement as MediaElement).Stop();
        MessageBox.Show(Watch.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString());
    }
```

Например.

Но почему-то не отрабатывает событие при нажатии кнопки Enter
Попробовал по-другому:

```
<MediaElement.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Command="{Binding Path=KeyPressedCommand}"
                          MouseAction="RightClick"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                          />
</MediaElement.InputBindings>
```

Все отрабатывает как надо.

В выводе никаких ошибок не пишет.
Но проблема в том, что мне необходимо повешать обработчик нажатия Enter клавиши.

Попробовал через такой подход:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=KeyPressedCommand}"                            
          CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=MediaElement}}"
        />
      </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Также нуль результата.

Comment: а элемент  в фокусе? При клике мышью он получает фокус, а при нажатии на ентер это само собой не происходит

Comment: Хм, странно, вроде у меня стояла строчка:
(mediaElement as MediaElement).Focus();
Добавил в хамл такое:
 Focusable="True"
И все стало работать.
Спасибо.